# On the composition of binary quadratic forms (esp. Gauss Disquitiones Arithmeticae Art. 235/236)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

In Composition of Binary Forms and the Foundation of Mathematics, Harold M. Edwards says that Gauss [cf. Art 235/236 of *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*] proved the following result.

**Theorem.** Let $f$ and $\phi$ be [integer] binary quadratic forms. If $f$ and $\phi$ can be composed, the ratio of their determinants must be a ratio of squares.

Let’s say I can factor a certain Diophantine equation as
$$(x_1^2+ay_1^2)(x_2^2+by_2^2)=x_3^2+cy_3^2,$$
where $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

As I read it, Gauss’s theorem implies that each of $a$ and $b$ must be an integer square. Am I correct?

Comment: yes. name $a = \alpha^2, b = \beta^2,$ all you have is $$  (x_1^2 + (\alpha y_1)^2)(x_2^2 + (\beta y_2)^2)$$

Comment: @WillJagy: Well, sure, just _setting them_ to squares makes the composition trivial… I need to be sure that I can make the claim that $a$ and $b$ _are necessarily_ squares.

Comment: summary by Buell https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/MINI/2010/buell.pdf

Comment: If i remember correctly, Gauss meant by determinant something different than the usual determinant, namely the discriminant of a quartic,  or something along those lines.

Comment: @ChrisCuster: I read somewhere that determinant meant 1/4 of the discriminant. These are the details I really need to figure out!

Comment: Actually, no. For any coefficients.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1098490_a_variation_of_the_same_identity  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1055482_streamlined_decision_of_the_previous_equation  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1053530_another_solution_almost_pythagoras_3  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1053462_another_solution_almost_pythagoras https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1053193_almost_pythagoras

Answer (score 1):

The post and the final comment of the OP on the post raises the issue of the historical and modern day definitions of determinant and discriminant.

These apply to quadratic forms given by

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2=\begin{pmatrix}x&y \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

In article $154$ Gauss defines the *determinant* of the quadratic form to be  $b^2-ac.$

Nowadays the *determinant* of the matrix is defined to be $ac-b^2$.

While the *discriminant* of the quadratic is defined to be $4b^2-4ac$.